# improve performance of a nested loop

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, delegates, multiprocessing

I have simplified my program for this example, so I basically load in a file and add the values from the file into a list.

```
IList<string> MyList = new List<string>();

Main () 
{
   foreach(Row r in InputFile)
   {
      foreach(Cell c in r)
      {
          AddToList(c.Value);
      }
   }
}

public void AddToTheList(string value)
{
   MyList.Add(value);  
}
```

I am looking to speed up the processing of the loop, I do not care about the order that the values are added.

I am thinking about running the loops in parallel and/or treating the AddToTheList method as an asynchronous fire and forget.

What is the most simple way to make the code use the servers processing power and speed up the total time to process the file?

Comment: What do you mean by `use the servers`?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is needing a code review for performance - checkout codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: What is the type of `InputFile`?

Comment: How big is the input ?

Comment: @rhughes sorry typo, my bad

Comment: @quantdev this is theoretical but I can assume a fairly large file of say 100,000 rows and 100 columns.

Comment: What do you do with the list? Can it be enumerated? You could do parallel.foreach on the outer loop if the processing is slower than the disk IO which would also reduce memory overhead. This all depends on how you are usign the data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update: If the inner loop is heavy enough to make this task CPU-bound (rather than IO-bound), then you could partition the loop using `Parallel.ForEach`. Here's an example:

```
Parallel.ForEach(InputFile, row =>
{
    foreach(Cell c in row)
        AddToList(c.Value);
});
```

Or, change the `AddToList` signature to return the value you need, and use PLINQ instead.

```
MyList = InputFile.AsParallel()
                  .SelectMany(row => row.AsParallel()
                                        .Select(cell => TransformCell(cell.Value))
                  .ToList();

public string TransformCell(string value)
{
   return value + " something";
}
```

Making `AddToTheList` a fire-and-forget async method is almost certainly not a good option. Exceptions thrown by that method would go unhandled, and depending on which framework you're using, these may crash the application.

---

Parallelizing the calls to AddToTheList is no good - this task is IO-bound.
The bottleneck is in how fast you can read data from disk.

Parallelizing disk access would be no good either. Having two or more threads reading the same file won't be any faster - they'll have to take turns anyway. See this answer to [Is it possible to use threads to speed up file reading?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3055497/857807)

> Use as many threads as you have files.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. If parsing rows and cells and adding values to the list is simple, doing things in parallel will not help you - you will be limited I/O, which is a lot slower than the CPU.

However, if parsing the rows takes time, and you're not really adding to a `List` but rather doing something more complicated, you can read rows from the files, and then handle the rows in parallel - just preallocate the memory for them (`List` lets you do that) and access each row's `List` positions in parallel.