# Splitting a text file and then work with the parts, using as many threads as there are parts

Tags: java, file, threadpool

I'm a beginner at java and files in specific. I have a task to count the occurrences of a certain symbol in a file, but I have to use a random number of threads. My idea is to split the file to however many threads I have to use, add it in a collection and then use ExecutorService with a fixed threadpool. But I'm not sure how to split the file in equally big parts. I'd be grateful of any tips!

Comment: [`File.length()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#length()) and [`RandomAccessFile`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html)

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by a random number of threads? Do you mean the number of cores available on a cpu! or pull a random number from a function and apply this many threads!

My view on solving this problem would be

1. Read the file in, then loop through its contents, store them in an array-list.
2. Split the array-list into arrays or smaller array-lists depending on your random number.
3. Create random number of threads and add them to thread-pool.
4. Pass smaller array/array-list to thread, logic in thread function ( if element.equals(symbol) {then count})
5. each thread returns a number, add these numbers and you have your occurrence rate.

Answer (score 0):

**How to split the file in equally big parts**

Splitting the actual I/O reads into several threads doesn't makes sense, as it'll be faster to read the whole file in a single thread (less random access and contention). [See this question for why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054442/is-it-possible-to-use-threads-to-speed-up-file-reading).

So you should simply read the file sequentially, chunk by chunk, and submit a symbol counting task each time the chunk gets sufficiently big.

java.util.Scanner is nice because it allows to stream though the file content without putting it entirely in memory, which is nice for files whose size exceeds your RAM.

```
    StringBuffer chunk = new StringBuffer();
    try(FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("filename.txt");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(inputStream, "UTF-8")) {

        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {

            chunk.append(sc.nextLine());
            if (chunk.length() > FILE_SIZE / THREAD_NB) {
                executorService.submit( () -> handleChunkSymbolCounting(chunk) );
                chunk = new StringBuffer();
            }
        }
    }
```

**NB: If you require a *physical splits* of the file**, ie if you want to create intermediary files like file001.txt, file002.txt... fileXXX.txt . Then it becomes desirable to parrallelize the file reads.

The code aboves still works, but instead of submitting counting tasks, you submit file writing tasks.