# Multithreaded reading/doing things with chars from character array in C

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I am trying to read a character array that contains the contents of many large files. The character array is going to be quite large, because the files are large, so I want to do it using multithreading (pthread). I want the user to be able to designate how many threads they want to run. I have something working, but increasing the number of threads does nothing to affect performance (i.e. 1 thread finishes just as fast as 10). In fact, it seems to be just the opposite: telling the program to use 10 threads runs much slower than telling it to use 1.

Here is the method for slicing up the character array according to the number of threads the user passes to the program. I know this is wrong, I could use some advice here.

```
//Universal variables
int numThreads;
size_t sizeOfAllFiles; // Size, in bytes, of allFiles
char* allFiles; // Where all of the files are stored, together
void *zip(void *nthread);
void *zip(void *nThread) {
     int currentThread = *(int*)nThread;
     int remainder = sizeOfAllFiles % currentThread;
     int slice = (sizeOfAllFiles-remainder) / currentThread;

     // I subtracted the remainder for my testing
     // because I didn't want to worry about whether
     // the char array's size is evenly divisible by numThreads

     int i = (slice * (currentThread-1));
     char currentChar = allFiles[i]; //Used for iterating

     while(i<(slice * currentThread) && i>=(slice * (currentThread-1))) {
        i++;
        // Do things with the respective thread's
        // 'slice' of the array.
        .....
    }
return 0;
}
```

And here is how I am spawning the threads, which I am almost positive that I am doing correctly:

```
for (int j = 1; j <= threadNum; j++) {
    k = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *k = j;
    if (pthread_create (&thread[j], NULL, zip, k) != 0) {
        printf("Error\n");
        free(thread);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
  }
for (int i = 1; i <= threadNum; i++)
     pthread_join (thread[i], NULL);
```

This is all really confusing for me so if I could get some help on this, I'd greatly appreciate it. I specifically am struggling with the slicing part (cutting it up correctly), and with not seeing performance gains by using more than one thread. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since C uses 0-based array-indexing, I'm 99.999% positive your for-loops should be of the form `for (int i=0; i<threadNum; i++)` and not `for (int i=1; i<=threadNum; i++)`

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Yes I initially had it as you described, but one thing I tried was dividing `sizeOfAllFiles` by `threadNum` so, by starting at zero, I got a floating point exception. Hence, the starting at one.

Comment: I agree with @JeremyFriesner. But then you should assign `j + 1` to `*k`. This should solve the `floating point exception` you described.

Comment: If you have 2 threads using common data then either 1) One thread is running at a time, or 2) they run on different cores and get worse performance due to data being in the wrong cache.  Which one were you hoping for?

Comment: @BenjaminJ. Ok I have done as described. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @stark I want the threads to be running concurrently, so that the whole thing is done faster.

Comment: @ipodfreak0313: Maybe you could read in the file in multiple blocks and then pass the single blocks to each thread.

Comment: @BenjaminJ. I would do that, but I am reading in multiple files and then appending them all together into a single `char*`, which is `allFiles`. Unless you mean breaking them up into blocks there, and then passing those blocks to `zip` with `pthread_create`?

Comment: What does "read a character array" mean? Sounds like you have an array of characters that already has somehow been placed in memory, and now you want to create _N_ new threads that will access it for some purpose. What is that purpose? I ask because the host that runs your program probably has only one memory bus, and if the time that it takes your threads to do whatever it is that they do with the characters is dominated by the time that it takes to _fetch_ the characters from main memory into local data caches, then adding more threads is unlikely to make it go any faster.

Comment: @SolomonSlow I want to read the character array, which is a bunch of files appended together. Then, I want to create a number of threads to do a run-length compression on the text in that character array. By breaking up the array into a certain number of parts and compressing them concurrently, I want to be able to perform the compression faster.

Comment: Run-length encoding is not compute-intensive. Each of your threads will spend most of its time in a loop, fetching the next byte from the source array, and comparing it to the previous byte. Sometimes, it will increment a counter. Other times it will write bytes to a destination array. My point is, it's going to spend a lot of time fetching data from the source, and that is not something that two threads can do at the same time. Every time one of your threads wants to fill a cache line with more source bytes, it will compete with other threads for access to the main memory bus.

Comment: @SolomonSlow is there a way I can implement multithreading in this scenario to see performance gains then? Should I be using a mutex or something on the character array? This is for a school assignment, we have to able to show that we can see performance gains by increasing the number of threads.

Comment: I don't know. Are any of your classmates doing any better? The problem that you have been asked to solve does not sound like a good candidate for multi-threading. It would be different if you had been asked to implement some encryption algorithm or some image processing algorithm where the threads would spend a larger portion of their time accessing their own private data. Operations on private data scale well with number of threads. Operations on shared data, not so much.

Comment: @SolomonSlow maybe I am supposed to substring the `allFiles` character array, and then pass each substring to its own thread? That way the threads aren't accessing shared data

Comment: Why are you dividing `sizeOfAllFiles` by `threadNum`? That makes no sense. Try printing out the byte range each thread is working on, and you should immediately see the problem.

Comment: Re, "substring the allFiles array..." It won't matter if the bytes start out in one big array or, in several smaller ones. Either way, the bytes are in main memory, and the threads will have to take turns using the _[system bus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bus_(computing))_ to fetch them. Throwing more CPUs at a problem helps when each CPU spends most of its time working in its own local _[data cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache)_. But run-length encoding is such a simple algorithm, that the CPUs will spend a large portion of time fetching bytes from main memory.

Comment: Re, Daniel Jour's answer: If different threads read different files, that may help somewhat, but if all of the files are on the same drive,... Your computer has only one interface to that drive, and all of the data will have to be moved through the interface in serial fashion, no matter how many threads are waiting for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm starting by throwing a test program at you:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <time.h>


bool
EnlargeBuffer(char ** const buffer_pointer,
              size_t * const buffer_size)
{
  char * larger_buffer = realloc(*buffer_pointer,
                                 2 * *buffer_size);
  if (! larger_buffer) {
    larger_buffer = realloc(*buffer_pointer,
                            *buffer_size + 100);
    if (! larger_buffer) {
      return false;
    }
    *buffer_size += 100;
  } else {
    *buffer_size *= 2;
  }
  *buffer_pointer = larger_buffer;
  printf("(Buffer size now at %zu)\n", *buffer_size);
  return true;
}



bool
ReadAll(FILE * const source,
        char ** pbuffer,
        size_t * pbuffer_size,
        size_t * pwrite_index)
{
  int c;
  while ((c = fgetc(source)) != EOF) {
    assert(*pwrite_index < *pbuffer_size);
    (*pbuffer)[(*pwrite_index)++] = c;
    if (*pwrite_index == *pbuffer_size) {
      if (! EnlargeBuffer(pbuffer, pbuffer_size)) {
        free(*pbuffer);
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  if (ferror(source)) {
    free(*pbuffer);
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}


unsigned
CountAs(char const * const buffer,
        size_t size)
{
  unsigned count = 0;
  while (size--)
    {
      if (buffer[size] == 'A') ++count;
    }
  return count;
}


int
main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  char * buffer = malloc(100);
  if (! buffer) return 1;
  size_t buffer_size = 100;
  size_t write_index = 0;
  clock_t begin = clock();
  for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
    {
      printf("Reading %s now ... \n", argv[i]);
      FILE * const file = fopen(argv[i], "r");
      if (! file) return 1;
      if (! ReadAll(file, &buffer, &buffer_size, &write_index))
        {
          return 1;
        }
      fclose(file);
    }
  clock_t end = clock();
  printf("Reading done, took %f seconds\n",
         (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
  begin = clock();
  unsigned const as = CountAs(buffer, write_index);
  end = clock();
  printf("All files have %u 'A's, counting took %f seconds\n",
         as,
         (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
}
```

This program reads all files (passed as command line arguments) into **one** big large `char * buffer`, and then counts all bytes which are `== 'A'`.  It also *times* both of these steps.

Example run with (shortened) output on my system:

```
# gcc -Wall -Wextra -std=c11 -pedantic allthefiles.c
# dd if=/dev/zero of=large_file bs=1M count=1000
# ./a.out allthefiles.c large_file
Reading allthefiles.c now ... 
(Buffer size now at 200)
...
(Buffer size now at 3200)
Reading large_file now ... 
(Buffer size now at 6400)
(Buffer size now at 12800)
...
(Buffer size now at 1677721600)
Reading done, took 4.828559 seconds
All files have 7 'A's, counting took 0.764503 seconds
```

Reading took **almost 5 seconds**, but counting (= iterating once, in a single thread, over *all* bytes) took a bit **less than 1 second**.

**[You're optimizing at the wrong place!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law)**

Using 1 thread to read *all* files, and then using *N* threads to operate on that *one* buffer isn't going to bring you places. **The fastest way to read 1 file is to use 1 thread.**  For multiple files, [use 1 thread per file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3055497/1116364)!

So, in order to achieve the speedup that you need to show for your assignment:

- Create a pool of threads with variable size.
- Have a pool of tasks, where each task consists of

  - read one file
  - compute it's run-length encoding
  - store the run-length encoded file
- let the threads take tasks from your task pool.

**Things to consider:** How do you *combine* the results of each task? Without requiring (costly) synchronization.

Comment: This was extremely helpful, thank you for putting so much effort into this. I have a question though. What do you mean by creating a pool of threads with variable size? And by a pool of tasks?