# faster way to read a file in chunks

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I want to read a file(>1GB) in chunks but without saving them into memory, so that I could stream every chunk using as few resources as possible.

For reading the file in chunks of `10MB` I am using this:

```rust
use anyhow::Result;
use futures::stream::FuturesUnordered;
use std::fs::metadata;
use std::io::SeekFrom;
use std::time::Instant;
use std::{env, process::exit};
use tokio::fs::File;
use tokio::io::AsyncReadExt;
use tokio::stream::StreamExt;
use tokio_util::codec::{BytesCodec, FramedRead};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let now = Instant::now();
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
    if args.len() < 2 {
        eprintln!("missing arguments: file");
        exit(1);
    }
    let file_path = &args[1];
    let fsize = metadata(&file_path).map(|m| m.len()).unwrap();
    let mut chunk_size = 10_485_760;
    println!(
        "file size: {}, chunk size: {}, parts: {}",
        fsize,
        chunk_size,
        fsize / chunk_size
    );
    let mut seek: u64 = 0;
    let mut parts: Vec<(u64, u64)> = Vec::new();
    while seek < fsize {
        if (fsize - seek) <= chunk_size {
            chunk_size = fsize % chunk_size;
        }
        println!("seek: {}, chunk: {}", seek, chunk_size,);
        parts.push((seek, chunk_size));
        seek += chunk_size;
    }

    let mut tasks = FuturesUnordered::new();
    for (pos, part) in parts.iter().enumerate() {
        tasks.push(read_file(&file_path, part.0, part.1, pos));

        // limit to only 4 tasks concurrent
        if tasks.len() == 4 {
            if let Some(t) = tasks.next().await {
                println!("{:#?}", t.unwrap());
            }
        }
    }

    while let Some(t) = tasks.next().await {
        println!("{:#?}", t.unwrap());
    }
    println!("Elapsed: {:?}", now.elapsed());
    Ok(())
}

async fn read_file(path: &str, seek: u64, chunk: u64, part: usize) -> Result<String> {
    let mut file = File::open(&path).await?;
    file.seek(SeekFrom::Start(seek)).await?;
    let file = file.take(chunk);
    let mut stream = FramedRead::with_capacity(file, BytesCodec::new(), 1024 * 64);
    let mut count = 0;
    while let Some(bytes) = stream.try_next().await? {
        count += bytes.len();
        // do something here, upload/stream the file PUT/POST
        // no CPU intensive so maybe spawn will not help much
    }
    Ok(format!("part: {}, size: {}", part, count.to_string()))
}
```

I am limiting the task to a max of 4 to also prevent  `too many files open` error.

The code works, but reading a file of [approximately 4GB](https://download.freebsd.org/ftp/releases/amd64/amd64/ISO-IMAGES/12.1/FreeBSD-12.1-RELEASE-amd64-dvd1.iso)(`4466092032`) in my system with SATA disks takes on average 230seconds.

I also tried with `tokio::task::spawn(...)` but the speed was about the same.

Any idea of how to improve the coded so that It could read the file faster?

Comment: I think this is less of a rust specific question... See related QA: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054442/is-it-possible-to-use-threads-to-speed-up-file-reading

Comment: mandatory question, did you compile in release mode ?

Comment: Yes, and testing with `cargo run --release  /path/to/file`

Comment: Can you try a command such a `time cat /path/to/file > /dev/null` to use as a baseline?

Comment: Hi @rodrigo, good hint, this is the current output: `84.93 real  0.03 user  2.45 sys`

Comment: "SATA disks". Nothing you do will ever make it marginally faster. Disks are slow. If you want to squeeze out last drop of IO performance, let OS provide direct pages instead of adding extra layer of buffering by directly memory mapping the file in question. Other than that, this can only be solved with getting a SSD and more RAM (so you can keep a bigger part of the file in memory at any given time). Also don't use 10MiB buffers, that's way more than you need. Usually more than 8-16KiB is too much and has no real performance benefit. Rust std uses 8KiB by default.

Comment: The "in-memory" buffer is 10Mib, then the chunk to be streamed is **64KB** `let mut stream = FramedRead::with_capacity(file, BytesCodec::new(), 1024 * 64);`

Comment: You will likely obtain much better results by just using a single thread and synchronous IO. Disks IO with async runtimes isn't fast, because it requires jumping between the async runtime thread and a threadpool thread. Trying to read multiple chunks of the file in parallel is not fast because it forces continuos seeks during IO - and disks (and their drivers) are optimized for sequential IO, and not for seeking

Comment: Like @Matthias247 said, disk I/O should not be done in multiple threads and it will only slow the process rather than making it faster. You can only load the file sequentially, this is the best you can get, however, you can somehow hide your computation time by reading the file and run tasks at the same time. When you filled your buffer, spawn a task and let it runs on another thread, and keep loading the next chunk. When the file is done, wait for all tasks. I think this is the best you can do.

Comment: Does this also apply to SSD  disks?